# How to change encoding in Restkit for IOS from Utf8 to Wincp1251

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, nsstringencoding, restkit-0.24.x

I get response from server in wincp1251 and restkit returns nil to my mapped object strings. I know restKit have a property defaultHTTPEncoding in RKClient(https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/commit/0ead8a922219ec42ec6dae6ebe59139a1fd589ae), how can I use this and can it helps me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. 
Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your server is returning JSON. If this is the case then the server needs to be updated because it isn't conformant to the [JSON spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). Specifically:

> 3. Encoding
>
>    JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is
>      UTF-8.

An important point to note is that RestKit doesn't unpack the response into a string, because the JSON deserialisation takes a data object (`NSJSONSerialization`). And again, the spec states:

> The data must be in one of the 5 supported encodings listed in the JSON specification: UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, UTF-32BE. The data may or may not have a BOM. The most efficient encoding to use for parsing is UTF-8, so if you have a choice in encoding the data passed to this method, use UTF-8.

So to handle your server response, if you can't change it, you'll need to handle the download yourself, convert the data to the appropriate encoding, unpack the JSON, and then create a mapping operation to use that.

Comment: but if I have xml response, not json?

Comment: you should really add that information to the question, but i guess the problem is the same and the serialisation is throwing an unknown / unsupported encoding error. you should really download and decode the data separately and then map it once its in a better format.

Comment: thank you very much, it's better explain, you save my day!

Comment: no problem. in future just try to add a bit more information about what you're doing. don't forget to vote and mark answers too :)